# Django Apache 2.4.18 Ubuntu 403

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

I am trying to configure my django app with Apache 2.4.18..

I am using Django 3.0.5 and Python 3.8.2., on Ubunu 16.04.

Everything works fine in runserver mode.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
```

This is my apache config gile

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
        ServerName servername.net
        DocumentRoot /srv

        Alias /static /srv/tacdb/mysite/static
        <Directory "srv/tacdb/mysite/static">
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /srv/tacdb/mysite/media
        <Directory "srv/tacdb/mysite/media">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/portal_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/portal_access.log combined

        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/srv/tacdb/virtualenvironment/project_1 python-path=/srv/tacdb
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/tacdb/mysite/wsgi.py

        <Directory /srv/tacdb/mysite>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

configtest is ok and server status is ok.

```
root@test-tools:~/srv# systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-04-02 15:18:20 UTC; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 26327 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25036 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 26356 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─26372 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─26375 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─26376 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─26377 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 02 15:18:19 test-tools systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 02 15:18:19 test-tools systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Apache2 web server...
Apr 02 15:18:19 test-tools apache2[26356]:  * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
Apr 02 15:18:20 test-tools apache2[26356]:  *
Apr 02 15:18:20 test-tools systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

I have tried to change permisions on the directory for apache user "www-data", but no luck.

I think that the folder level permisions are according to Apache version, based on my research.

Any ideeas?

Thanks a lot! Do let me know if other info is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as granting permision. I have used the /srv/ from another location. I am not sure - security wise - if this is the best solution to gand folder access.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /srv
```

I think i am better now since it reads my configuration file (i have encountered another error).